# User mode qemu and KVM

Tags: kvm, qemu

When running user mode qemu for target x86 on a target x86 (or just target arch = host arch), will qemu use KVM, transfer control to the directly to the CPU or will it be interpreting the instructions.

Comment: the user mode in qemu is for transparently running binaries compiled for a CPU on another CPU (eg. running x86 linux binaries on an arm linux machine without having to emulate a full computer with peripherals, OS, etc). `qemu` will JIT-translate the instructions to the target machine's, and the system calls into native system calls. KVM cannot have anything to do with this.

Comment: not to be confused with the user-mode network stack (slirp).

Answer (score 1):

A few circumstantial evidences that user mode does not use KVM:

- the userland executable `qemu-x86_64 --help` does not show a `--kvm` option, as is present for the full system executable `qemu-system-x86_64 --help`
- we can see both input instructions and the binary translated instructions with:

  ```
  qemu-x86_64 -d in_asm,out_asm hello.out
  ```

  A commented example: [How does native android code written for ARM run on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005303/how-does-native-android-code-written-for-arm-run-on-x86/44505097#44505097)

Now, for the more interesting question, could it in theory work?

I'm not sure, but on the [gem5 simulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gem5), which also has an analogous user mode (called syscall emulation), there was at least some serious investigation of this possibility by AMD, and they concluded it would be possible: http://www.m5sim.org/wiki/images/5/53/2015_ws_12_KVM-in-SE.pdf

Something was actually merged in 2014:  adbaa4dfde96d5aaf84adf0ae4989ef880aad726 "kvm, x86: Adding support for SE mode execution". But when I tried on 3ca404da175a66e0b958165ad75eb5f54cb5e772 it failed with `KeyError: 'OsKernel'`, gotta investigate/ask further.